# How does the Sorcerer archetype Eldritch Scrapper interact with Robe of Arcane Heritage?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, sorcerer, bloodline

The [Eldritch Scrapper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/archetypes/paizo---sorcerer-archetypes/eldritch-scrapper) replaces the 1st, 9th and 15th level bloodline powers.

If a level 8 Eldritch Scrapper puts on a [Robe of Arcane Heritage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-of-arcane-heritage), what will happen? So far, me and my friend have sussed out three potential candidates:

Option 1: The Eldritch Scrapper will advance the Martial Flexibility class feature, due to it replacing the bloodline power.

Option 2: The Eldritch Scrapper will gain hte 9th level bloodline power, but it will be removed again when she reaches 9th level, to be replaced with the Martial Flexibility ability.

Option 3: Nothing will happen, as the robe refers to Bloodline Powers specifically, and Martial Flexibility is not a bloodline power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 3 appears to be the strict RAW ruling as I cannot find anything that would indicate otherwise and despite replacing bloodline powers Martial Flexibility is not a bloodline power. I would probably opt to go with option 1 since it does replace the bloodline power it seems fair to give you the replacement.